# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Cross Domain Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make an Ajax call to Indian Railway API which provides various data in the JSON format. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
    function getData()
    {
    var theUrl = 'http://api.railwayapi.com/between/source/gzb/dest/anvt/apikey/56237/'
    $.ajax({
        url:  theUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       },
        error: function(data){
        alert('ERROR');
    }
    });
}   
</script>
```

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="getData()"></button>
</body>
```

It is a very simple call but I cant understand why it keeps showing Error alert box. Few things that I have tried:
1. I get an error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." if I keep data type as json.

2. On searching for this error, I saw that json should be changed to jsonp, I get the following errors:

   Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://api.railwayapi.com/between/source/gzb/dest/anvt/apikey/56237/?callback=jQuery111208570126367267221_1424232589162&_=1424232589163".

It added call back when I changed data type to json, which I understand is correct.

While the other error is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ?callback=jQuery111208570126367267221_1424232589162&_=1424232589163:2

which is on this line "response_code": 200,

When I run the API in my browser through URL, it runs perfectly. When I look under developer tools then under Sources in Chrome it does show the JSON response. If that is the case, then why is it not showing alert for "Success".

Link to access the API is:
http://api.railwayapi.com/between/source/lko/dest/anvt/apikey/56237/

How can I tell the request is cross domain for sure?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: the error is because, the said resource is not supporting `jsonp`, also since there is no `CORS` support, you will have to use a proxy based approach to access the said api

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Indian Railway API doesn't appear to support JSONP.

If you read their docs, you'll see this line:

> Requests should be made from your server only and not from the clients browser or app.

So, you can use a proxy server that allows CORS, but that might violate their Terms of Service. It also allows essentially anyone in the world to see your API key.

This might not be a realistic option for you, but the best solution would be to write a server-side application that communicates with the Indian Railway API and then sends data back to your front-end without exposing the API key.

Comment: Are there any good examples that I can look at to achieve your solution? Also, just wondering, which documents are you referring to where you read "Requests should be made from your server only and not from the clients browser or app." ? I can't seem to find it. What does it really mean by "requests from your server only and not client's browser"? Whenever I accessed the api, it was from my browser. Also, I am making this to work on PhoneGap, does that change or help me in anyway? Thanks.